# Rails creating two model in one form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

Hi I'm trying to create two object from different models in one form. They are connected by a has_many/belongs_to relationship. The event has_many pictures wich is polymorphic because can be associated with others models. I'm getting Can't mass-assign protected attributes: picture if I set :picture in attr_accesible it's saying me "unknown attribute: picture".

Here is my form code :

```
    <%= form_for @event, :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal' } do |f| %>
  <div class="control-group">
    <%= f.label :titre, :class => 'control-label' %>
    <div class="controls">
      <%= f.text_field :titre, :class => 'text_field' %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="control-group">
    <%= f.label :Date, :class => 'control-label' %>
    <div class="controls">
      <%= f.date_select :dday, :class => 'date_select', :start_year=>Date.today.year, :end_year=>1905 %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="control-group">
    <%= f.label :lieux, :class => 'control-label' %>
    <div class="controls">
      <%= f.text_field :lieux, :class => 'text_field' %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="control-group">
    <%= f.label :description, :class => 'control-label' %>
    <div class="controls">
      <%= f.text_area :commentaire, :class => 'text_area', :rows => 4 %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <%= f.fields_for @event.pictures.new do |p| %>
    <%= p.text_field :name, :placeholder=>"Nom de votre image" %>
    <%= p.file_field :image %>
  <% end %>
```

and my models code

```
 class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :dday, :lieux, :titre, :commentaire, :picture
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :pictures, :as => :imegeable ,:dependent => :destroy
    default_scope :order => :dday
    validates :dday, :titre, :presence=>true
end
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while since I've done any Rails work, so this might've changed since I last did it, but I think you need to specify that `accepts_nested_attributes_for :pictures` on your Event model.

Comment: When I'm doing it I get a new error "No association found for name `picture'. Has it been defined yet?"

Comment: Fixed a typo: `pictures`, rather than `picture`.

Comment: sorry I don't understand what you mean?

Comment: My original answer said `accepts_nested_attributes_for :picture`.  I changed this to `accepts_nested_attributes_for :pictures`.  Try `accepts_nested_attributes_for :pictures`.

Comment: I get the can't mass assign again

Answer (score 0):

Try to change last fields_for from your code to:

```
<%= f.fields_for :pictures do |p| %>
  <%= p.text_field :name, :placeholder=>"Nom de votre image" %>
  <%= p.file_field :image %>
<% end %>
```

Add to your model:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :pictures
```

And change attr_accessible in your model to:

```
attr_accessible :dday, :lieux, :titre, :commentaire, :pictures_attributes
```